# Generate a DES key and use cipher for encryption

Tags: java, cryptography

I want to learn about cryptography with java and I found 
[these](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/security/f09/lectures/JCA.pdf) slides on the internet. On page 9 I found on an example and I tried to use it. However, the following code is not compiling. Where is the mistake?

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class Gen_DESAES_key{


byte[] message = "Hello World".getBytes();

KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
SecretKey desKey = keygenerator.generateKey();

Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,deskey);

byte[] encryptedMessage = desCipher.doFinal(message);
}
```

Comment: What compiler error do you get?

Comment: This is the error: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 deskey cannot be resolved to a variable

 at Gen_DESAES_key.enc(Gen_DESAES_key.java:15)
 at apples.main(apples.java:7)

Comment: There's your problem (or at least one of them). You declared it as `desKey` but then tried to use `deskey` - capitalisation is important in Java.

Comment: @jsheeran Thanks a lot! I really didn't notice that. But now I get a totally new error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Unhandled exception type NoSuchAlgorithmException
 Unhandled exception type NoSuchAlgorithmException
 Unhandled exception type NoSuchPaddingException
 Unhandled exception type InvalidKeyException
 Unhandled exception type IllegalBlockSizeException
 Unhandled exception type BadPaddingException

 at Gen_DESAES_key.main(Gen_DESAES_key.java:11)

Comment: Have a read about [exception handling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/). Those are examples of checked exceptions, which the compiler requires you to handle. The quick and dirty way to do this is to add a `throws` clause as in the answer below.

Comment: @jsheeran Thanks, I will go trough it. One last question: How can I display the encrypted Message? Seems like "System.out.println(encryptedMessage)" is not working, since its always outputting the same string (even if I change the plaintext).

Comment: @Benjamin `System.out.println(new String(decryptedMessage));` and you also could encode it as Base64: `System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedMessage));`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Fix #1: Fixing the variable name

Variable names are [case-sensitive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html#naming) in Java. Your variable name is `desKey` and not `deskey`.

### Fix #2: Wrapping your code into a method and handling exceptions

Apart from that, you must wrap your code into a method, as shown below:

```java
import javax.crypto.*;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Gen_DESAES_key {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                                                  NoSuchPaddingException,
                                                  BadPaddingException,
                                                  IllegalBlockSizeException,
                                                  InvalidKeyException {

        byte[] message = "Hello World".getBytes();

        KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey desKey = keygenerator.generateKey();

        Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);

        byte[] encryptedMessage = desCipher.doFinal(message);
        System.out.println(new String(encryptedMessage));
    }
}
```

Please mind that your code will throw a bunch of exceptions that must be handled by a `try`-`catch` block or declared in the `throws` clause of the method. For more details, refer to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

### Bonus #1: Using Base64

To avoid some weird characters when showing the encrypted message, you can encode it with [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). If you are using Java 8 or later, you can use [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html):

```java
System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryp‌​tedMessage));
```

### Bonus #2: Decrypting your message

To decrypt your encrypted message, use:

```java
desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);
byte[] decryptedMessage = desCipher.doFinal(encryptedMessage);

System.out.println(new String(decryptedMessage));
```

Comment: Your base64 encoder from the comments above is not working for me, I get the error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Base64 cannot be resolved
 encryp‌​tedMessage cannot be resolved to a variable

 at Gen_DESAES_key.main(Gen_DESAES_key.java:26)

Comment: @Benjamin The code above uses [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) that has been introduced in Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to write a method, and there is a spelling mistake in a variable name:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class Gen_DESAES_key{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] message = "Hello World".getBytes();

        KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey desKey = keygenerator.generateKey();

        Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,desKey);

        byte[] encryptedMessage = desCipher.doFinal(message);
    }
}
```